# Magento 2: How to connect Openbravo Erp with magento2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

Hello i want to connect my openbravo erp with magento2 website, there is any extension available if yes please suggest me

Answer (score 1):

Openbravo does have an Openbravo Magento Connector Module for connecting Openbravo ERP and Magento eCommerce systems under commercial licensing. With the help of this module, one can synchronize the customer data, product information and sales orders using a scheduler job.

Please go through the [Openbravo Magento Connector](https://centralrepository.openbravo.com/openbravo/org.openbravo.forge.ui/ForgeProjectDetail/Openbravo%20Magento%20Connector) project page for downloading the related modules.

Please check the project [wiki](http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/Projects/SigmaInfoSolutions-OpenbravoMagentoConnector) page for technical specifications and how-tos.

In case, if you are using Openbravo 2.50, please find the installation guide [here](https://centralrepository.openbravo.com/openbravo/org.openbravo.forge.ui/AllForgeModules).

Also available extension: as http://www.nextbits.eu/magento-open-bravo-erp-integration-service.html